# ¿Cómo devuelvo este web service en un array?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo este web service que me trae un array en json..

```
[
    {
    codigo_producto: "3630",
    unidad_medida: "UND ",
    barcode: "7704495003630"
    }
]
```

He estado utilizando algunas funciones de php como:

```
$barCode = fopen('http://dynaenterprise.com/rest/bar-code/'.$articulo->codigo,"4");
dd($barCode);

$barCode = file('http://dynaenterprise.com/rest/bar-code/'.$articulo->codigo);
dd($barCode);
```

Pero estas solo me retornan en un array pero dentro de el un string...

```
    array:1 [▼
  0 => "[{"codigo_producto":"16177","unidad_medida":"UND ","barcode":"7707052619732"}]"
]
```

y necesito obtener el array para tomar el valor de "barcode":"7707052619732" del webservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que obtienes es un array de strings, entonces debieras poder acceder al primer elemento haciendo:

```
$primer_registro_str = $barCode[0];
$convertido_en_array = json_decode($primer_registro_str,true);
$primer_registro anidado= $convertido_en_array[0];
```

El contenido de $primer_registro_anidado ahora es un array asociativo del tipo

```
[
"codigo_producto"=>"16177",
"unidad_medida"=>"UND ",
"barcode"=>"7707052619732"
]
```

Ahora supongamos que te llega una respuesta de muchos elementos y sólo quieres quedarte con aquel que tenga `barcode` 7707052619732.

```
$respuesta= [
    '[{"codigo_producto":"16177","unidad_medida":"UND ","barcode":"7707052619732"}]',
    '[{"codigo_producto":"99999","unidad_medida":"XYZ ","barcode":"9999999999999"}]'
];
```

Esto se puede hacer con una combinación de `array_map` y `array_filter`. Dos funciones de PHP que son muy lindas porque ilustran cómo el lenguaje es absolutamente inconsistente en el órden de los parámetros. Pero en fin, de funcionar, funciona.

```
$array_de_arrays = array_map(function($registro_str) {
    $decoded= json_decode($registro_str,true);
    return $decoded[0];
}, $respuesta);


$elemento_con_barcode_770 = array_filter(array_values($array_de_arrays),function($un_array) {
    return $un_array['barcode']=='7707052619732';
});

print_r($elemento_con_barcode_770[0]);
```

Nótese que no usé comparación `===` en el array_filter porque dependiendo de las opciones que le pases a `json_decode` puede que tengas strings como barcodes. De hecho puede que **quieras** strings.

Velo funcionando en 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/48a33e61b13a59e198646ec54204fcb94b1842a5

Comment: Excelente tu explicación, he aprendido algo de ti en este comentario que has puesto. Una pregunta más.. ¿Cómo hago para extraer unicamente el valor '7707052619732' en una variable?

Comment: Ya no es necesario bro.. con el array_column() extraje el barcode ¡INFINITAS GRACIAS!